# I want to set jpanel size which is called in jtree

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtree, jsplitpane

Here is the piece of code which i'm using to call jpanel

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JSplitPane sppane= new JSplitPane();
JTree tree = new JTree ();
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
frame.setsize(screenSize.getWidth(),screenSize.getHeight());
DefaultMutableTreeNode node1= new DefaultMutableTreeNode(childofthistree[0]);
eRMSNode[] childnode1= new eRMSNode[]{
            new eRMSNode("Jpanel1","jpanelimageonlefttree.gif"); }
DefaultMutableTreeNode parentnode=(DefaultMutableTreeNode) 
tree .getModel().getChild(root, 0);
for (Node Childtree : detailsoftree) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(Childtree);
    parentnode.add(node);
}
```

now jpanel1 is displayed.but problem is that i'm not able to get fixed size on right side of jpanel1 which is displayed on right side.

Comment: Layouts are more likely to honor the preferred size, than the size.

Comment: plus: even if showing code snippets, don't show those that obviously can't compile ...

Comment: Sorry guys and @kleopatra , I couldn't see this code and not edit it -.-
This is a disgrace to us :P

Comment: Again, posting an **SSCCE** is what I am advising, not code snippets (using imaginary classes or otherwise).